# Limpar requisição anterior e realizar nova apenas com o ultimo elemento com jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

estou com uma dúvida no jQuery que desenvolvi, eu estou populando os dados no estilo "*combobox*" e as requisições e respostas estão corretas porém, meu problema está quando eu clico novamente no meu "*.item-carousel*" e eu faço minhas requisições GET ele mantém os últimos *club* clicados e ao invés de fazer apenas uma requisição com o último ele faz com todos os antigos + o último.

```
$('.item-carousel').click(function() {
    let club = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $.get('/api/year', {
        club: club
    }, function (src) {
        $('select[name=year]').empty();
        $('select[name=year]').append('<option value="0">Selecione</option>');

        $.each(src, function (key, value) {
            $('select[name=year]').append('<option value=' + value['id'] + '>' + value['name'] + '</option>');
        });
    });

    // Realiza a busca dos meses com base no ano
    $('select[name=year]').change(function () {
        let year = $(this).val();

        $.get('/api/months', {
            club: club,
            year: year
        }, function (src) {
            $('select[name=month]').empty();
            $("select[name=month]").append('<option value="0">Selecione</option>');

            $.each(src, function (key, value) {
                $('select[name=month]').append('<option value=' + value['id'] + '>' + value['name'] + '</option>');
            });
        });
    });

    // Gera a tabela das transações do mês
    $('select[name=month]').change(function () {
        let month = $(this).val();
        let year = $('select[name=year]').val();

        $.get('/api/balance', {
            month: month,
            year: year,
            club: club
        }, function (data) {
            $('#balance-money').empty();
            $('#month-balance').empty();

            $('#balance-money').append('R$ ' + data[0]['total']);

            $.each(data, function (key, value) {
                $('#month-balance').append(`
                    <tr>
                        <td><p class="text-center">` + value['client'] + `</p></td>
                        <td><p class="text-center">R$ ` + value['balance'] + `</p></td>
                        <td><p class="text-center"> ` + value['status'] + `</p></td>
                        <td><p class="text-center">` + value['created_at'] + `</p></td>
                    </tr>
                `);
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Pra ficar mais claro, anexo minhas requisições que estão sendo feitas[image: Requisições realizadas]

Comment: usa o cache: false dentro do seu $.get({ cache: false, club: club, year: year [...]

Comment: Quando vc coloca um _event handler_ dentro de outro, sempre que vc disparar o evento vai criar uma nova instância do que está aninhado. Ex.: toda que que vc chamar `$('.item-carousel').click(function() {` vai criar um novo `$('select[name=year]').change(function () {` e vai se acumulando, ou seja, o onchange vai ser executado múltiplas vezes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não aninhe manipuladores de eventos dentro de outro, porque irá acumular esses manipuladores aninhados.

Por exemplo, ao colocar:

```
$(elemento).click(function(){
   $(elemento).change(function(){
   }
});
```

Toda vez que o `click` for chamado, irá gerar um novo `change`, ou seja, no primeiro `click` irá gerar um `change`; no segundo `click` irá gerar outro `change` que será disparado 2 vezes e assim em diante.

O correto seria separar os manipuladores, um fora do outro:

```
$(elemento).click(function(){
});

$(elemento).change(function(){
}
```

Só que a o evento `change` precisa da variável `club` que é criada dentro do evento `click`, e separando os eventos a variável `club` no evento `change` vai ser inválida. Você teria então que fazer essa variável ter escopo global.

Declare a variável `club` fora, e atribua o valor a ela dentro do `click`:

```
let club;
$(elemento).click(function(){
   club = $(this).attr('data-id');
});

$(elemento).change(function(){
}
```

Mas é preciso também impedir que o `change` execute o AJAX se a variável `club` estiver sem valor. Para isso você coloca o AJAX dentro de um `if`:

```
let club;
$('.item-carousel').click(function() {
    club = $(this).attr('data-id');

    $.get('conecta.php', {
        club: club
    }, function (src) {
       console.log(src);
    });

});

 // Realiza a busca dos meses com base no ano
 $('select[name=year]').change(function () {
     let year = $(this).val();

      if(club){
        $.get('conecta.php', {
            club: club,
            year: year
        }, function (src) {
             console.log(src);
        });
      }
 });

 // Gera a tabela das transações do mês
 $('select[name=month]').change(function () {
     let month = $(this).val();
     let year = $('select[name=year]').val();

      if(club){
        $.get('conecta.php', {
            month: month,
            year: year,
            club: club
        }, function (data) {
          console.log(data);
        });
      }
 });
```